# Expresion regular numeros decimales

Tags: c#, regex, validación

estoy tratando de crear una expresion regular para que aceptes ese tipo de numeración

1. 1.111.111,0000
2. 111.111,0000
3. 0.0000
4. 111.1111

La expresión que estaba usando era la siguiente

> [0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[,]\d*

aquella expresión solo acepta 1.111.111,0000 pero estoy tratando de que pueda tomar los otros casos.

Comment: Sobre qué lenguaje usarás después la expresión regular ?

Comment: lo usare sobre C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu expresión regular

```
[0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[,]\d*
```

estás diciendo:

1. Uno o dos dígitos numéricos seguidos de un punto
2. Seguidos de uno, dos o tres dígitos numéricos y otro punto
3. Seguidos de uno, dos o tres dígitos numéricos y una coma
4. **Opcionalmente**, seguidos de N decimales

Eso es inconsistente. Primero, porque estás exigiendo que el número sea lo suficientemente grande como para tener dos separadores de miles. Segundo, porque requieres el separador decimal, cuando un número entero no tiene por qué tenerlo. Tercero, porque si el número es más grande, y tiene tres separadores de miles, no calza. Cuarto, porque el separador de miles ocurre cada 3 cifras, no cada "una a tres cifras".

Una expresión regular del tipo:

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$/
```

Significa en cambio:

1. Uno a tres dígitos
2. Seguidos de cero o más ocurrencias de `.###`
3. Opcionalmente seguidos de un separador decimal y más de un decimal

Esto hace que, por ejemplo `1.000,` no cumpla. No tiene sentido la coma si no hay decimales.

Probémoslo:

```js
var numeros = ['1.111.111,0000',
'111.111,0000',
'0.0000',
'111.1111'];

numeros.forEach(function(numero) {

 if(/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?$/.test(numero)) {
   console.log(numero, 'SÍ calza');
 } else {
   console.log(numero, 'NO calza');
 }

});
```

Si te fijas, `0.0000` no calza, porque hay cuatro cifras juntas sin un separador de miles de por medio. Tendría que ser `00.000`. (Aunque aceptar ceros a la izquierda no tiene realmente ningún propósito...)

`111.1111` tampoco calza, por la misma razón. Tendría que ser `1.111.111`.

El separador de miles siempre requerirá **tres números y sólo tres números** a continuación.

Si lo que quieres es que acepte números formateados tanto con el sistema latino (puntos para separar miles, coma para separar la parte decimal) como con el sistema inglés (justo al revés) debieras hacer dos expresiones regulares y probar si calza una o la otra. De lo contrario vas a tener una expresión inconsistente que permita mezclar puntos y comas en desorden.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta ! aprovechando tengo otra consulta

Comment: 000111111119 una expresion regular para esa cadena... la cantidad de números enteros es de 7 o 8 y el ultimo numero puede ser 0,1-9 o una k

Comment: Esto es una pregunta nueva? `000111111119` tiene 14 caracteres pero dijiste 7 u 8. ¿Quieres verificar un RUT? De todos modos debieses hacer una nueva pregunta en vez de ponerla en los comentarios y con gusto te responderé

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución elimina agrupadores adicionales:

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:[.]\d{3})*(?:[,]\d+)?)
```

Está basado en la respuesta anterior.